# MySQL - How to select a column so that the outcome be a tree structure?

Tags: mysql, select, split, tree

If i have a given column with the following snapshot

```
"A - B - 1"
"A - B - 2"
"A - C - 1"
"A - C - 2"
"X - B - 1"
"X - B - 2"
"X - C - 1"
"X - C - 2"
```

Which select should I run so that the outcome be

```
"A",  "", ""
"", "B", ""
"",  "", "1"
"",  "", "2"
"", "C", ""
"",  "", "1"
"",  "", "2"
"X",  "", ""
"", "B", ""
"",  "", "1"
"",  "", "2"
"", "C", ""
"",  "", "1"
"",  "", "2"
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: What is the pattern? How did you decide what to trim out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the positions of each char in the string is fixed you can do this quite easily using string functions.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (  
  select distinct 
    substring(col1,1,1) col1, 
    null col2, 
    null col3, 
    substring(col1,1,1) ord 
  from t

  union all

  select distinct 
    null, 
    substring(col1,5,1), 
    null, 
    concat(substring(col1,1,1),substring(col1,5,1))
  from t

  union all

  select distinct 
    null, 
    null, 
    substring(col1,9,1),
    concat(substring(col1,1,1),substring(col1,5,1),substring(col1,9,1))
  from t  
) a order by ord;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67a9d/6)

This query would return:

```
|   col1 |   col2 |   col3 |
|--------|--------|--------|
|      A | (null) | (null) |
| (null) |      B | (null) |
| (null) | (null) |      1 |
| (null) | (null) |      2 |
| (null) |      C | (null) |
| (null) | (null) |      1 |
| (null) | (null) |      2 |
|      X | (null) | (null) |
| (null) |      B | (null) |
| (null) | (null) |      1 |
| (null) | (null) |      2 |
| (null) |      C | (null) |
| (null) | (null) |      1 |
| (null) | (null) |      2 |
```

**UPDATE**

The answer provided above is valid if you have a fixed-length string - All samples consider strings of length equal to one. However, if you need a variable-length string, do as follow

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 1) col1, 
    NULL col2, 
    NULL col3, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 1) ord
  FROM t

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DISTINCT 
    NULL, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 2), ' - ', -1), 
    NULL, 
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 2), ' - ', -1)) ord
  FROM t

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DISTINCT
    NULL, 
    NULL,  
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', -1),
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', 2), ' - ', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ' - ', -1)) ord
  FROM t
) a ORDER BY ord;
```